# How to set Windows 11 (or 10) sign-in/lock screen cycling wallpaper resolution to 3440 x 1440?

Tags: windows-10, resolution, windows-11

P.S. This problem persisted for me in Windows 10 and 11 (when i upgraded to 11)

I run my Windows 11 desktop with a 3440x1440p ultrawide monitor.

The result is a horrendous stretched mess as the automatically cycled wallpapers shown on my lock screen is badly distorted and pixelated.

I cant seem to find any settings to would set the resolution of my lock screen to the monitor's native resolution. Conversely, when I switch to solely using my 1920x1080p secondary monitor, the lockscreen resolution is fine and the wallpaper crisp and sharp, without me setting anything at all.

Comment: Have you tried ultrawide wallpaper images?  https://unsplash.com/wallpapers/screen/ultrawide

Comment: @John nope, but i'll give that a try, thanks. So im assuming by default the lockscreen cycling wallpapers are stuck at 1920x1080? I do love the quality of those.

Answer (score 0):

The Spotlight images are downloaded by Windows from Bing.
The images have their width, mostly in the 16:9, and Windows does not
attempt to select based on the monitor's dimensions, only stretching them
to fit. The results for your very wide monitor are not the best.

You will need to use your own images that are better fitted to your
monitor.

A comment above recommended the
[HD Ultrawide Wallpapers](https://unsplash.com/wallpapers/screen/ultrawide),
but you might need to search a bit to find images of your particular
resolution (or even just of your width/height aspect).